# How facebook embed media of others?

Tags: facebook, embed, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a app that you get link of videos of sites like youtube, vimeo, blip.tv, etc, and self embed like facebook do.

When you post a link of that sites on facebook, this links get embed in timeline/comment and you can play this video without go to another page.

How is this done? The Facebook separate all services and handle this services separately or exist a protocol that the third services implement to your own media appear embeded in sites like facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Your page has to implement certain **OpenGraph** concepts. More information can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Here's a step-by-step tutorial on how to integrate an app/page with OpenGraph:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

If you'd like to have similar functionality on your own web page, you could check out [oEmbed](http://www.oembed.com/) and [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/).